# Sending the contents of selected file as well as parameters in ajax request in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I am using the following piece of  code for sending the contents of selected file to the server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title></head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script>
        function startRead() {

           $.ajax({
    url: 'https://abc',
    data: document.getElementById('files').files[0],
    contentType: 'application/exe',
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
    ,error:function(data)
    { console.log(data);
    }
});
                }

    </script>

    <body>    
    <input type="file" id="files"  onchange="startRead()" />

</body>    
</html>
```

As you can see the ajax reuqest, I ve passed the file content in data .
But along with that i also need to pass parameters of two textboxes in the given html
Also the file contents will be used as inputstream on server side and reconstructed as file again
How do it pass them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try sending an object instead:

```
data: {
        file : document.getElementById('files').files[0],
        txt1 : document.getElementById("the-id-of-text-input-1").value,
        txt2 : document.getElementById("the-id-of-text-input-2").value
      }
```

or more jQuery way:

```
data: {
        file : $('#files').get(0).files[0],
        txt1 : $("the-id-of-text-input-1").val(),
        txt2 : $("the-id-of-text-input-2").val()
      }
```